# Why does MongoDB allow NaN value when NaN is not supported by JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, mongodb, nan

I'd like to here from a Mongo expert on this.  Answers so far have been from JavaScript side.

Here's my scenario.  I used Python/Pandas to read CSV and convert to JSON to store in MongoDB.  I also have a Python AWS Lambda API exposed to JavaScript.  Data with a bad value ended up with a value of NaN, and MongoDB accepts that just fine, and Python dictionary handles it fine, and serializes to JSON.  But JavaScript cannot parse it.  My interim fix was to change NaN to 0 for now (in the database).

I'm trying to get understanding of why MongoDB/Python allow this, but JavaScript does not. Is it because lack of standards in JSON itself?

If I put this in JSONLint.com, it quickly identifies the issue.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "value": NaN
}
```

In JavaScript, we get a ParseError on an Ajax call (abbeviated version):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://da987tkpjg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/PROD",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "body":{ ...
            }
        }),
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` is not a valid JSON value.

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.
> ([source](https://www.json.org/json-en.html))

You'll need to filter out these values in python.

This isn't a "lack of standards" in the JSON spec, you're just outputting invalidly formatted JSON.

---

As for why MongoDB is returning `NaN`:

I'm *guessing* it's a fallback then something that isn't a `number` is entered into a field that should've been a `number`. For type safety, MongoDB can't just return that something, so it gives you the best it can tell you: `NaN`.

Note that `NaN` is a *JavaScript*  concept. JSON is inspired by JS's object notation, but it's otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Then how does MongoDB accept it, isn't it JSON based?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a fallback then something that isn't a `number` is entered into a field that should've been a `number`. For type safety, MongoDB can't just return that something, so it gives you the best it can tell you: `NaN`. Note that `NaN` is a _JavaScript_  concept. JSON is inspired by JS's object notation, but it's otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Pandas set the value to NaN in a dataframe, that was put in a Python dictionary, Python stored it in MongoDB using PyMongo. So I'm trying to learn how MongoDB "JSON" is different from JavaScript "JSON" - if that makes sense. Then Lambda serializes "JSON" using Python as well, and it had no problem with it.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The JSON spec is clear, `NaN` is not allowed, simple as that. You'll need to fix this problem on the server's end.

Comment: The problem has been fixed.  The question is not whether Javascript supports NaN, but how to work full-stack with inconsistencies.

Comment: MongoDB stores BSON, not JSON.  It's a format that is a binary encoded representation.  It supports more data types than JSON, for example you can store dates in BSON.

Answer (score 1):

That's because NaN is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

> Numbers
>
> Leading zeros are prohibited. A decimal point must be
> followed by at least one digit. NaN and Infinity are unsupported.

Comment: Then how does MongoDB accept it, isn't it JSON based?